# Trying to import CSS, Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I am trying to use the `Vue-Quill` package as a text-editor.
Following the [Installation](https://vueup.github.io/vue-quill/guide/installation.html#npm-yarn) instructions on their webpage with NPM.

Vue-Quill installs, without an error in the browser:

```
import { QuillEditor } from '@vueup/vue-quill'
import '@vueup/vue-quill/dist/vue-quill.snow.css';
```

But after trying to import the CSS like in the [instructions](http://%20https://vueup.github.io/vue-quill/guide/usage.html#in-single-file-component) and make it available globally, it throws me the following error:

```
./node_modules/@vueup/vue-quill/dist/vue-quill.snow.css 
(./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-
3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-oneOf-
3-2!./node_modules/@vueup/vue-quill/dist/vue-quill.snow.css)
```

and in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
```

In other StackOverflow question I already got the tip to:

1. Make sure the file is actually a file (not a directory)
2. Give it the permissions 777

So far, non of the steps introduced didn't yield any good result.
So, how do I get to resolve this issue for importing a CSS?

Comment: Did you include the full error? There seems to be more in the title than in the body...

Comment: I added the console output as well to the question